# Only one checkbox is checked in Checkbox list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a function in asp.net c# application

```
     public void FillAfterClose(string Names)
    {

            string[] arrGroup = Names.ToString().Split(',');

            foreach (object obj in arrGroup)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < chklLicenceTypes.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (chklLicenceTypes.Items[i].Text == obj.ToString())
                    {
                        chklLicenceTypes.Items[i].Selected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

in aspx file I am binding a checkbox with name and value pair via code

```
     <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklLicenceTypes" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="false" 
CausesValidation="false" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatLayout="Table" runat="server">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

After rendering the page in browser the checkboxlist are filled with

- Property and Casualty  [ ]
- Accident and Health   [ ]
- Life [ ]
- Casuality [ ]
- None  [ ]

If string Names contains value like "Property and Casualty, Accident and Health,    Life" then Function FillAfterClose only makes "Property and Casualty" checkbox enabled and rest are omitted...
I want that "Property and Casualty, Accident and Health, Life" checkboxes should be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string is exactly:

```
var names="Property and Casualty, Accident and Health, Life";
```

Then I would see that there is a problem with the spaces in the end of the split. I would change this line:

```
string[] arrGroup = Names.ToString().Split(',');
```

this will result to:

```
new []
    {
        "Property and Casualty",
        " Accident and Health",
        " Life"
    };
```

To this line:

```
string[] arrGroup = names.Split(',').Select (s =>s.Trim()).ToArray();
```

this will result to:

```
new []
    {
        "Property and Casualty",
        "Accident and Health",
        "Life"
    };
```